# App Downloader Like soft32.com

Tags: php, c++, .net, download

I have a download site and I want user to first download a downloader which then downloads the actual program.

First, I want to know which language is better to do this? 
.Net is a good choice, but user must have it installed and it may not be the case.
I think c++ is the best because there won't be any component needed.

Second how to inject the download detail like it's link and information to the downloader with PHP?

Finally, is there any good sample or basic source code to accomplish this?

The downloader must support resuming and multi segment download.

This is not for profiling or getting user data. It's just because we have internet issues in our country, Iran :( . We see a lot of partial downloads from the server. This way we make it resumeable and faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this for profiling or getting user data be aware that in many countries this is illegal, also it's likely that it will make you lose users rather than gain ones.

Any library it's not granted to be installed on the user device, also are you ready to code as many application as possible for all the platforms ? From the iOS devices to Windows XP you need to code your own application.

I don't think that this answer can be answered, it covers a very wide topic and it's prone to legal issues.

Comment: No, that's not for profiling or getting user data. It's just because we have internet issues in our country. We see a lot of partial downloads from the server. This way we make it resumeable and faster.

Comment: We only consider windows, windows xp the main share

Comment: @user1831956 a solution that can fit your needs can be something similar to a torrent client, with peers that can keep the download even if 1 node ( your main server ) is down. Decide what language you want to target and what platforms you want to consider, an easy solution can be the C# language for Windows but it's really hard to port, there are many torrent libraries out there by the way, so you can solve this with a relatively small effort. https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+torrent+library

Comment: The server is located in Canada and there is no problem with server. The main problem are clients that have unreliable connections.

Comment: @Ali who are you ? :P By the way it's basically the same thing, if i was you, with an unreliable connection and the need to make something available for download for a considerable amount of users, i would probably go for something similar to this.